# How to find indexes by alias name in elasticsearch 6.1.1 java api

Tags: java, elasticsearch

In the previous versions of elasticsearch i can use this piece of code to get all of the indexes and aliases with it

```
getClient().admin().cluster().prepareState()
.execute().actionGet().getState().getMetaData().getAliasAndIndexLookup()
```

which will return a map with the index name as the key and the aliases as the value and i could just iterate thru the map to see the index of a certain alias.

But i'm having trouble as to how to achive this in elasticsearch-6.1.1 using RestHighlevelClient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi to anyone who might stumble into this problem i have solved it by using the Rest low-level client.

```
Response response = restHighLevelClient()
                    .getLowLevelClient()
                    .performRequest("GET","/_cat/aliases?format=json", headers);
```

This will return a json response and i just used jackson to save the values.